# Parse datetime string with Eastern Daylight

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date string as "2017-08-08T17:08:29 EDT -0400". We are rewriting the Java App to C#. In Java by parsing this date to the SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z Z"), the validation is done. But in C# when I try to parse it to DateTime I am getting an error as this is not a DateTime string. How can I validate this date using C#?

Thanks

Comment: It _isn't_ a valid datetime string. What does 2017-08-08-08 mean?

Comment: string is not correct `2017-08-08-08T17:08:29 EDT -0400`, no such date looks like `2017-08-08-08`

Comment: sorry the additional 08 is typo. I am confused too after seeing that format. that's why I am posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestions and questions:

1. What's 2017-08-08-08?
2. I would use either EDT or -0400, not both, e.g:

   ```
       var s = "2017-08-08T17:08:29 -0400";
       var format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz";
       CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

       var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, provider);

       Console.WriteLine(d);
   ```
3. Better, use NodaTime and its parsers. Check out https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/offsetdatetime-patterns

Comment: sorry the additional 08 is typo. I am confused too after seeing that format. that's why I am posting this question.